# How to create and at the same time connect to a other model in a Implicit many-to-many relations?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, relational-database, relationship, prisma

I am new to Prisma. I have stuck on Prisma.brand.create method. Here is the model:

```
model Category {
  id String @id @default(cuid())
  slug String @unique
  name String @unique
  image String?
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  user   CMS_users @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String
  brands Brand[]
}

model Brand {
    id String @id @default(cuid())
    slug String @unique
    name String @unique
    image String?
    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    user   CMS_users @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId String
    categories Category[] 
}
```

This is generated schema in the MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `Brand` (
  `id` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `userId` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Brand_slug_key` (`slug`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Brand_name_key` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `Category` (
  `id` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `userId` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Category_slug_key` (`slug`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Category_name_key` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `_BrandToCategory` (
  `A` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `B` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `_BrandToCategory_AB_unique` (`A`,`B`),
  KEY `_BrandToCategory_B_index` (`B`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The goal is here to create a Brand, at the same time connect one or more categories to that brand.

How Do I create it on Prisma client? right now it is like this:

```
 prisma.Brand.create({
      data: {
        name: name,
        slug: slug,
        userId: user,
        image: uploadedImage.secure_url,
        categories: {
          create: [
            { category: { connect: { id: "ckzpl0del0014vcv2ctift2f1" } } }
          ]
        }
      },
      include: {
        categories: true
      }
    })
```

The error shows:

PrismaClientValidationError:
Invalid `prisma.brand.create()` invocation:

```
{
  data: {
    name: 'wassss',
    slug: 'wassss',
    userId: 'd5eea2a7-78d0-41d9-b090-171c9d7100cc',
    
    categories: {
    ~~~~~~~~~~
      create: [
        {
          category: {
            connect: {
              id: 'ckzpl0del0014vcv2ctift2f1'
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  include: {
    categories: true
  }
}
```

Unknown arg `categories` in data.categories for type BrandUncheckedCreateInput. Available args:

type BrandUncheckedCreateInput {
id?: String
slug: String
name: String
image?: String | Null
createdAt?: DateTime
userId: String
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case [`connectOrCreate`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#connectorcreate) API should solve your issue.

```js
const result = await prisma.brand.create({
    data: {
      name: "samsung",
      slug: "samsung",
      userId: "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
      categories: {
        connectOrCreate: {
          create: {
            name: 'phone',
          },
          where: {
            name: 'phone',
          }
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

In this case `connectOrCreate` tries to find a category with name: 'phone', if found then it connects to it. If it can't find category then a new category named 'phone' will be created.